# Pysnow module (Python for Servicenow) - how to create requested items?

Tags: python, servicenow

I recently start using pysnow-module for automating my work at Servicedesk. My problem is that i don't know how to create Requested Items.

I have managed to create new incidents and new requests, also update them. I have also succeeded in modifying Requested Items, but i'm stuck at not knowing how to turn Requests into Requested Items.

I've tried following pieces of code, all starting with this

```
s = pysnow.Client(instance='Secret domain', user='Secret-user', password='Secret')
```

Then continuing with following tries:

```
def new_ritm():
   result = s.insert(table='sc_req_item', payload={'field1': 'value1', 
   'field2': 'value2'})
print(result['number'])
luo_uusi_ritm()

File "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 51, in <module>luo_uusi_ritm()
File"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 47, in new_ritmresult = s.insert(table='sc_req_item', payload={'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'})
File "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 90, in insert return r.insert(payload)
 File "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 108, in insert return self._get_content(response)
File "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 290, in _get_contentreturn content_json['result']
KeyError: 'result'
```

---

Also tried modifying REQ, insert new values:

```
result = s.insert(table='sc_req_item', payload={'sc_req_item.request': 
'REQ0994143'})
```

But get an error:

```
"File "xxxxxxxxxxxxx, line 290, in _get_content
return content_json['result']
KeyError: 'result'
```

---

EDIT:
Suggestion 1:
I couldn't add the

> "request_params={'sysparm_display_value': 'true'})"
>   , because it gives me an "Unexpected argument" error

I entered the following code:

```
 s = pysnow.Client(instance=XXXX,user=XXXXX,password=XXXXXX)


 try:
     result = s.insert(table='sc_req_item', payload={'field1': 'value1', 
     'field2': 'value2'})
 except pysnow.UnexpectedResponse as e:
    print("%s, details: %s" % (e.error_summary, e.error_details))
```

Which gives me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "XXXXXXXXXXXX", line 63, in  stack_experiment()
>
> File "XXXXXXXXX", line 59, in stack_experiment result = s.insert(table='sc_req_item', payload={'field1': 'value1','field2': 'value2'})
>
> File "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 90, in insert return r.insert(payload)
>
> File "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 108, in insert return self._get_content(response)
>
> File "XXXXXXXXXXX", line 290, in _get_content return content_json['result']
>
> KeyError: 'result'

---

Suggestion 2:

> Maybe you are confused using Client.insert instead of Request.insert

I am confused about it. Should i change the starting code "s = pysnow.Client(etc."?

I went to read the docs one more time and i've understood for new requests, i should use pysnow.Request, so i tried once more with:

```
 r = pysnow.Request(instance='Secret domain', user='Secret-user', 
 password='Secret', method='POST', table='sc_req_item')

try:

    result = r.insert(payload={'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'})  

except pysnow.UnexpectedResponse as e:

    print("%s, details: %s" % (e.error_summary, e.error_details))
```

And i got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "xxxx", line 
 7, in <module>
  r = pysnow.Request(instance='xxxx', user='xxxx', 
 password='xxxxx', method='POST', table='sc_req_item')
  File "xxxxx", line 29, in __init__
   self.default_payload = kwargs.pop('default_payload')
KeyError: 'default_payload'
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**:  My problem is with Requested Items.

1. Try the following, and [Edit] your Question to adding the Output of `print(...` or any `Traceback`:

   ```
   try:
       result = s.insert(table='sc_req_item', 
                         payload={'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'})
   except pysnow.UnexpectedResponse as e:
       print("%s, details: %s" % (e.error_summary, e.error_details))
   ```
2. Maybe you are confused using `Client.insert` instead of `Request.insert`?

   > [pysnow.Request — Creates a new request object](http://pysnow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html#pysnow.Request)
   >   insert(payload)
   >
   > Inserts a new record with the payload passed as an argument
   >   Parameters: payload – The record to create (dict)
   >   Returns:    Created record
3. Setting request parameters
   The request_params dict argument can be used to set request parameters. This example returns names from fields with linked tables, instead of the standard URL for ServiceNow dot walking.

   ```
   import pysnow
   # Create new client with SN request parameters
   sn = pysnow.Client(instance=instance,
                      user=username,
                      password=password,
                      request_params={'sysparm_display_value': 'true'})
   ```

---

Try this example from the Documentation:

> pysnow: [Getting a single record](http://pysnow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/full/get_one.html)
>
> See the pysnow.Request.get_one() documentation for more details.
>
> ```
> import pysnow
> # Create client object
> s = pysnow.Client(instance='myinstance', user='myusername', password='mypassword')
> # Query for 'INC01234' on table 'incident'
> r = s.query(table='incident', query={'number': 'INC01234'})
> # Fetch one record and filter out everything but 'number' and 'sys_id'
> res = r.get_one(fields=['number', 'sys_id'])
> # Print out the result
> print(res)
> ```

Comment: It worked like a charm. But, i have to clarify that with Incidents i don't have any problems, i can update them and create new ones. My problem is with Requested Items. I don't know how to create one and i tried modifying commands from the Pysnow Documentation, which didn't work. Requests i can create, but not Requested Items, which my company uses alot.